# Asynchronous web service SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, asynchronous

I have an interface that I've exposed as a regular SOAP web service. One method of the interface consists for the client to send a file to the server, then the server processes the file and returns a result file. Processing the file may take some time, so I think using asynchronous invocation of this method is a better idea. I thought about the following flow:

The client invokes the asynchronous method and sends the file using an attachment (MTOM).
When the file is received by the server, a response is sent back to the client indicating that the file has been received and that it will be processed shortly.
Once the file is processes, a response is sent back to the client indicating it has been processed and a result file is returned in the response also as an attachment.

Is it possible using SOAP with CXF?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Callback` approach of `Asynchronous InvocationModel`.

> Callback approach - in this case, to invoke the remote operation, you
>   call another special method that takes a reference to a callback
>   object (of javax.xml.ws.AsyncHandler type) as one of its parameters.
>   Whenever the response message arrives at the client, the CXF runtime
>   calls back on the AsyncHandler object to give it the contents of the
>   response message

More information can be had from the following:

[Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From your answer, I understand that all this configuration appears on the client side. I guess that the server side remains synchronous. I thought that this configuration should be done on the server side possibly using asynchronous servlets (from 3.0). What is the difference?

Comment: OK.Normally when in the case of synchronous service, only one thread will be used to complete the request and response.But in the case of Asynchronous service, one thread will be used separately to serve the response from the server.So basically , you need to choose such kind of framework that supports this feature.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911491/writing-async-service-using-cxf-with-java-first-approach

Comment: According to what it is explained in http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/19/asynchronous-jax-ws-web-services.html, my question is, if I use the CallBack model, may my service client be written in C#? Since the configuration is done on the client side, the C# equivalent of JAX-WS must support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you use some tool like WSDL2Java for client generation, you can even choose to generate an asynchronous client.
It will generate for you a callback handler with empty methods for each of the service operations and exceptions of the service. You then can just implement those methods to set the actions to do when the response is received.
Remember that when an asynchronous call is done a new thread is started.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Once you receive the file, you may return the request id to client and start processing on server side and do maintain various states of processing. Client can come back in different interval, and will receive the processing status or the output if it is completed.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like a polling model when the client has to poll the server to know if the processing is completed. I would like the server to send back the response when the processing is completed.